# Where do I begin to learn practical software development?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I've heard of people making their own software products and selling it. Sadly, I don't know anybody of such calibre personally. I want to know where could I learn such software design principles and architectures (not for a personal project like taught in the plethora of YouTube videos that exist, but real world application with concurrent user handling and scalability). It would be helpful if someone who knows these things could point me to the right resources.
Thank you.
[Please only mention resources that you are personally sure of.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an unhelpful answer, but this is exactly what people go to university to learn - moving from a basic understanding of personal techniques to a broader more professional understanding of techniques used in industry. (source: studied computing science at university)

Otherwise, just keep working on small projects and you'll learn about it as you go. It can be a daunting task to create something on the scale of Facebook yourself without the expertise, but modern day Facebook wasn't created by one person, and they didn't have all the expertise when they started. You learn either by being taught, or by starting at the start and facing lessons as you encounter them and by learning how to deal with them in the future.